# Why is not supported difference operator in a sorted set?

Tags: redis

Hello I am learning about redis, an in the topic about sorted sets, doesn't have a reference about difference between two sets, whey the sorted sets doesn't support this operator Thanks

Comment: Yes https://redis.io/commands#sorted_set

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry isn't SDIFF for sets and not sorted sets ?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but if you search for ***redis zdiff*** you can see a few discussions on the topic of why it doesn't exist.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/redis-db/mLekyeN7Haw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While zdiff is not supported as part of Redis syntax there are some things you can do:

1. Use a LUA script that imitates the zdiff commands like this [script](https://gist.github.com/Aeonrush/7fff79d4b16fbfde74ae3ad78646d285)
2. Write your own Redis module (new in Redis 5.x) which can be implemented in low level c code and create an efficient zdiff command. You can read about Redis modules [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiJ3LHusYHjAhVTnVwKHYFbD3EQFjADegQIARAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fredis.io%2Ftopics%2Fmodules-intro&usg=AOvVaw2pq6V7DD4sitP7aSWmWX3-).

Enjoy your Redis development!